# java.io.exception this may not be a PDF file

Tags: android, pdf

I'm coding an Android app and trying to convert a PDF file to an image.
I'm using the library [`pdfviewerlibrary`](https://github.com/StEaLtHmAn/AndroidPDFViewerLibrary). This is the beginning of my code:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/manual.pdf");
long len = f.length();
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.NEW(channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size()));
PDFFile mPdfFile = new PDFFile(bb);
```

The problem is that, when I create the new `PDFFile`, it throws the exception

> java.io.exception this may not be a PDF file.

Obviously `manual.pdf` is a PDF file, but when I check the `length` it says 0, and I know it shouldn't...

I don't know what to do, anyone already had the same problem??

Comment: Print out f.getAbsoluteFile() and check if the path is correct; if f.length() returns 0, but you're sure your manual.pdf is not an empty file (did you check that?), then the path seems to be wrong.

Comment: i faced the same issue in past.check your PDF file extension

Comment: I checked the path and its "/storage/sdcard0/manual.pdf", it looks good to me (the file is in the root of the sd card). 
And I checked its not empty, and its a pdf file, I can open it and watch it in my pc so... :S

Comment: @Hugaro: Did you fix the issue? I am facing the same issue. Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: Hi @karthi, actually I discovered that with those methods you can just convert the text included in the pdf,but not the images. 
In my case I was working with an application which generated a pdf with text and images, my mission was to transform this pdf into an image, and I did it but just including the text, as it was enough for me i didn't follow researching. 
I'm sorry I can't be more helpful, good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the problem, remove the slash before the file name. The code will be:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"manual.pdf");
long len = f.length();
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.NEW(channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size()));
PDFFile mPdfFile = new PDFFile(bb);
```

Comment: I also tried without the slash, but in that case the exception is thrown when I initialize the RandomAccessFile. 
It says: "open failed: ENOENT (no such file or directory) 

I'm desperate :S thank you for your time anyway

Comment: I think that the pdf file is corrupted, try another one.

Comment: That may because you haven't the permission of READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE